# Mysql query - Count the founded rows on joined table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables

First one: Offers

id
user_id
user_data

The second one: Orders

id
user_id

### order_data

Now, the goal is, to get the list of the OFFERS including the count of the orders table, where orders.user_id == offers.user_id

the result must be:

id
user_id
orders_count

---

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Right, and what did you try?

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 1):

You have all the ingredients, it sounds like you just need to write the SQL. It would probably be something like:

```
select
a.id, a.user_id, count(*)
from offers a
inner join orders b on
a.user_id = b.user_id
group by a.id, a.user_id;
```